# Deleting mail messages from exchange server from an outlook add-in

Tags: outlook, vsto, exchangewebservices

I am writing a add-in for outlook 2010 (windows desktop version) using Visual studio tools for office.
The outlook client has a exchange email configured.
I want to allow the user to delete messages from the exchange server.
I think it should be do-able if I use the exchange web services or use some third party library but in order to do this I would have to ask the user to re-specify his exchange email configuration to my add-in - I want to AVOID this.

I am wondering if there is a easier way to do this by calling some outlook or VSTO API, basically I am looking for a way to tell outlook to delete these messages from the server from my add-in's code.
I have tried searching the VSTO documentation but have gotten no results.

Comment: Are these emails in a folder in their Mailbox?

Comment: yes, they are in exchange - as in if you login to the outlook web interface (owa) you can see the mails in his inbox

Comment: I may be reading too much into your question, but yes it is certainly possible to delete any kind of Outlook content with the Outlook Object Model.  Every item (e.g. MailItem, AppointmentItem, etc.) has a Delete method. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether you have the cached mode enabled for the Exchange profile or not... But you can use the [Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863343.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of Outlook items. The `Delete` method deletes a single item in a collection. Note, the Delete method moves the item from the containing folder to the Deleted Items folder. If the containing folder is the Deleted Items folder, the Delete method removes the item permanently.

If you have the cached mode enabled in Outlook you need also to sync with the server to erase the item there too. The [SyncObject.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863925.aspx) method begins synchronizing a user's folders using the specified Send\Receive group. For example, a VBA macro illustrates that:

```
Public Sub Sync() 
  Dim nsp As Outlook.NameSpace 
  Dim sycs As Outlook.SyncObjects 
  Dim syc As Outlook.SyncObject 
  Dim i As Integer 
  Dim strPrompt As Integer 
  Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
  Set sycs = nsp.SyncObjects 
  For i = 1 To sycs.Count 
    Set syc = sycs.Item(i) 
    strPrompt = MsgBox( _ 
      "Do you wish to synchronize " & syc.Name &"?", vbYesNo) 
    If strPrompt = vbYes Then 
      syc.Start 
    End If 
  Next 
End Sub
```